# Java if-statement currentTimeMillis, check if specific time has passed

Tags: java, if-statement, long-integer

I've ran into an odd problem. I'm trying to check if the current time is greater than powertimer. When I run the method the if-statement returns true even though `powerup.getPowertimer()  - System.currentTimeMillis()` is greater than 0 which I tested by printing out the result.

```
this.powertimer = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000;
public long getPowertimer() {
    return this.powertimer;
}

if ((powerup.getPowertimer()  - System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0) {
    System.out.println(powerup.getPowertimer() - System.currentTimeMillis());
    powerup.reversePower(player);
    expired.add(powerup);
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

To check if current time has "passed" the `powertimer` timeout, you do

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() > powerup.getPowertimer()) {
    ...
}
```

---

Note that your line:

```
if ((powerup.getPowertimer()  - System.currentTimeMillis()) > 0)
```

is equivalent to

```
if (powerup.getPowertimer() > System.currentTimeMillis())
                            ^
                            |
                wrong direction of inequality
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the subtraction around the wrong way. Do this:

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis() - powerup.getPowertimer() > 0)
```

Always remember this:

> delta = final - initial

Thanks to my high school physics teacher Geoff Powell for this little gem I have used often in my life.